# 301 Redirect for specific url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to edit the URL of a page (only one page called `meto.php`) to a custom URL.

It is important that the `meto.php` file located in sub-directory `/pob/`
i want to change this `www.domain/pob/meto.php` to  `www.domain/pob/define.php`

When visitor type this address `www.domain/pob/meto.php` address bar show this address: `www.domain/pob/define.php`

Please note `define.php` file does not exist.

I tried this code in `.htaccess` file at `/pob/` (not root directory):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/pob/$1 [r=301,nc]
Redirect 301 meto.php define.php

//also
    Redirect 301 /meto.php http://www.domain.com/pob/define.php

//

RewriteRule ^meto.php define.php
```

Unfortunately all of the above tries fails.

Server info:

Apache Version  2.2

PHP: 5.5

Answer (score 0):

You can not rewrite your files using Redirect Directiv of mod_alias , it is used for external redirection.

Try mod_rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/pob/$1 [R=301,L]
#1) redirect "/pob/meto.php to "/pob/define.php"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /meto.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /define.php [NC,L,R]

 #2) rewrite "pob/define.php" to "/pob/meto.php"
 RewriteRule ^define\.php$ /pob/meto.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: thank you for reply the second code got me this error 'too many redirects occurred trying to open' and the second code got me 500 internal error. I put this code at .htaccess at /pob/ director not root

Comment: Any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: yes , something about my script and i put this code between `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`  block

Comment: @Paula The code is working fine on my apache server. I have  2.2 version of apache. I have tested it twice. You were using 301 permanent redirect in your previous code, Web browsers always cache 301 redirects for better performance, may be its not working because of that. Clear your browsers cache.